# jquery scrollLeft 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, var

I need the children of my parent div to scroll horizontally.
The scroll should be animated and it's supposed to scroll 100% of the parents width.

I either need to know how to use percentages here or how to write a correct var for this problem.

Here's my code:

```
var maxscroll = $('#content').width()

$('.prev').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=maxscroll"
  }, 500);
});

 $('.next').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#content').animate({
   scrollLeft: "+=maxscroll"
  }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses the concept of a wrapper for the inner content - I used a P here with fixed width to illustrate - so that you can get the max content width and use that as the scroll amount.

```js
var maxscroll = $('#content')[0].scrollWidth

$('.prev').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#container').animate({
    scrollLeft: -1 * maxscroll
  }, 500);
});

 $('.next').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#container').animate({
   scrollLeft: maxscroll
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
div#container {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 3px solid #666;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  #content {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='prev' >Prev</button>
<button class='next' >Next</button>

<div  id="container" ><p id ='content'>Hello</p></div>
```